# PDO Prepared Select statement for checking if a user exists

Tags: email, select, pdo, prepared-statement, match

I'm a pdo newbie and need to prepare and execute some php/pdo code:
This code works to allow me to create users in my database:

```
    // Perform Insert / Update
$STH = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email) values (:username, :email)");
$STH->bindParam(':username', $username);
$STH->bindParam(':email', $email);
    try{
    $STH->execute();
    redirect_to(signupsuccess.php);
    }
catch(PDOException $e) {  
echo "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND); 
}
    }
```

but before I put that data into the database I need to do a check to make sure the email  doesn't already exist in the database. I need to do a SELECT, something like:

```
    $STH = $dbh->prepare("SELECT FROM users (email) values (:email)");
$STH->bindParam(':email', $email);
try{
    $STH->execute();
      }
```

and I know I need to add

```
    "WHERE something matches '$_POST'email') something.." ...
```

I'm totally lost at this point..I can do this without PDO but I want to start using PDO's prepared statements..Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a simple select.  I recommend Using bind value if you may possibly have a null email.

```
$STH = $dbh->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email");
$STH->bindValue(':email', $email);
try{
    $STH->execute();
}
```

Then just check if any records are returned.  If so, Update, don't insert.  good luck.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I assume the bind part will help to prevent sql injection by preventing the email supplied from going anywhere other than in the prepared slot (:email) in the statement?

Comment: Also: do I have to use $STH2 instead of $STH? I'm already using $STH for the insert/update and I'm not closing the connection (with <?php $dbh = null; ?> ) until much later..

Comment: Also: Is there any harm/benefit in adding LIMIT 1?

Comment: Feel free to reuse the connection.  There should be no harm in adding a LIMIT 1, in fact it can improve performance for the select (since you only care if any duplicate email exists) especially if email is not an indexed column.

Comment: Yes, the binding in this example specifically, would prevents injection.